# script to automatically create ext4 and swap in unallocated diskspace

Tags: partitioning, cloning

I have to setup/install a number of machines. Some machines have Windows 7 installed. Some machines not. The machines have either 0, 2, or 3 partitions. Every machine has enough free diskspace (20 to 250 GB).

I installed an "golden client" and built a `.tar` archive of this client. Now, every client boots up a small linux via pxe, and runs a script. This script should create an ext4 and a swap partition using the whole free space. After this, mount the ext4-partition, copy tar, chroot, and so on.

I can create partitions using fdisk. But how can I figure out the partition number of the new partition. For example, do I have to mount `/dev/sda3` or `/dev/sda1`?

Furthermore, how can I figure out if the partition is unallocated space, and how much space there is?